# Python: How to Speed Up API Requests?

Tags: python, pandas, api, request, multiprocessing

**Problem:** I am trying to extract data through an API Service. A single request can take anywhere from 3 to 10 seconds. There are roughly 20,000 rows of data from a Pandas DataFrame to input into the API Call. I have managed to speed it up a bit through multiprocessing, but it's still running very slow. Any suggestions?

**Code:**

```
def scored_card_features2(source, n_batches):
    """Multiprocessing version of Scored Card Features Function
       Returns reason for rating
    """

    # read in source data and convert to list of lists for inputs
    data = pd.read_excel(source)
    data = data[['primary_bank_report_id', 'primary_tu_credit_report_id', 'purpose']]
    inputs = data.values.tolist()

    def scored_card_map(i):
        """form request to scored card service and retrieve values"""

        url = "url/FourthGen?bank_report_id=%s&credit_report_id=%s&" \
                  "&loan_purpose=%s" % (i[0], i[1], i[2].replace(" ", "%20"))

        r = requests.get(url)

        try:
            d = json.loads(r.text)
            l = [d['probability_of_default'],
                            d['condition'],
                            d['purpose_of_loan'],
                            d['rating'],
                            d['bank_report_id'],
                            d['reason_for_rating'],
                            d['credit_report_id']]
            return l

        except:
            l = [np.nan] * 7
            return l

    # inititate multithreading
    with Pool(n_batches) as p:
        vals = p.map(scored_card_map, inputs)
        result = pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=['Probability of Default', 'Condition', 'Purpose of Loan', 'Rating', 'Bank Report ID',
                                  'Reason for Rating', 'Credit Report ID'])
        result = result.dropna(how='all')
        return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # model features
    start = time.time()
    df = scored_card_features2('BankCreditPortalIDsPurpose.xlsx', multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1)
    df.to_csv('scored_card_features.csv', index=False)
    end = time.time()
    print(end-start)
```

Comment: The only thing I can see at a glance is to replace `json.loads` with just `r.json()` (requests has a built-in json decoder - though this may not be any faster). The real delay is presumably all in the API returning data, and potentially being rate-limited, and this is out of your control.  Do they offer an API for bulk requests? Otherwise running the code through a [profiler](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/profile.html) is your only other option to find the 'slower' bits.

Comment: Celery should be able to make it faster.

Comment: You may be able to improve times by using an async library like `requests-futures`. I don't know if that will be faster than a `Pool` (I definitely can't see it being slower) but might be worth a go.